# swift Mac OS: make trackpad reflect display size for NSTouch events

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to make touch events take the trackpad as the display when moving it.

What I mean in this is:

Consider a Mac laptop display, and imagine it to be exactly the size of the trackpad, or so this is how I want the touch events to be implemented. There was a normalised x y coordinate property before in NSEvent which may have given me this, but it seems to have been deprecated.

Below are touchBegan and touchMoved overrides and what I mean:

```
override func touchesBegan(with event: NSEvent) {
    CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(CGMainDisplayID(), event.location(in: overlayScene))
    let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: tick)
    sineNode.addAudioPlayer(player)
}

override func touchesMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
    let location = event.location(in: overlayScene)
    guard let node = overlayScene.nodes(at: location).first else{
        if currentSKNode != nil{
            currentSKNode = nil
        }
        return
    }
    if currentSKNode != node{
        currentSKNode = node
    print(node.name)
    let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: tick)
    sineNode.addAudioPlayer(player)
    }
}
```

Imagine a fgraph reader where x and y axes are centred at exactly width/2 and height/2 of the trackpad. When I touch anywhere on it, this should reflect exactly on the apps window which is set to full screen.

Currently, the mouse cursor seems to go only partially across the display when I make a full left to right move, hence trying to reposition the mouse cursor to the position of the NSView, or in this case the SKScene.

Comment: [`NSTouch.normalizedPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstouch/1534031-normalizedposition) doesn't look deprecated to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out, as Kent mentioned, normalised position is not deprecated, but I was looking into NSEvent not NSTouch.

Here's the code for anyone who would stumble upon the same requirements. Works fine, just need to figure out now how to make this as responsive as possible.

```
override func touchesMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let touch = event.touches(matching: .moved, in: self.sceneView).first
    let normalised = touch!.normalizedPosition
    let translated = CGPoint(x: self.width*normalised.x - self.widthCenter, y: self.height*normalised.y - self.heightCenter)
            guard let node = self.overlayScene.nodes(at: translated).first else{
                self.currentSKNode = nil
                return
            }
            if self.currentSKNode != node{
                self.currentSKNode = node
                let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: self.tick)
                self.sineNode.addAudioPlayer(player)
            }
    }
}
```